# Job failed on Cloud ML after successful completion of 1000

Tags: tensorflow, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

I had walked through this cloudML tutorial on census data: cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction  in which the Job was successful. However, when I walk through this tutorial on flower image data:  https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-classify-images-with-tensorflow-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow  my training task appears to successful based on the completion of 1000 steps from the log. However, upon completion from this snapshot [StackDriver logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XAjr.png), it says job failed. I have tried using the same structure replacing the command-line arguments from the census data walkthrough, deleted and recreated JOB_ID and --output_path user argument, used the STANDARD_1 scale tier but to no avail. Any help I can get from the community would be appreciated. Thanks!

Below are the errors, you can see that popped out towards the tail end of the logs snapshot:

```
{
 textPayload: "The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 542, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 305, in main
    run(model, argv)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 436, in run
    dispatch(args, model, cluster, task)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 477, in dispatch
    Trainer(args, model, cluster, task).run_training()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 241, in run_training
    self.eval(session)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 283, in eval
    self.model.format_metric_values(self.evaluator.evaluate()))
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 95, in evaluate
    return metric_values
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 960, in managed_session
    self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 788, in stop
    stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 386, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 234, in _run
    sess.run(enqueue_op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
NotFoundError: Error executing an HTTP request (HTTP response code 404, error code 0, error message '')
     when reading gs://project-166422-ml/User/flowers_User_20170522_121407/preproc/eval
     [[Node: ReaderReadUpToV2 = ReaderReadUpToV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordReaderV2, input_producer, ReaderReadUpToV2/num_records)]]
Caused by op u'ReaderReadUpToV2', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 542, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 305, in main
    run(model, argv)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 436, in run
    dispatch(args, model, cluster, task)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 477, in dispatch
    Trainer(args, model, cluster, task).run_training()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 241, in run_training
    self.eval(session)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 283, in eval
    self.model.format_metric_values(self.evaluator.evaluate()))
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 57, in evaluate
    self.eval_batch_size)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 310, in build_eval_graph
    return self.build_graph(data_paths, batch_size, GraphMod.EVALUATE)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 231, in build_graph
    num_epochs=None if is_training else 2)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/util.py", line 52, in read_examples
    filename_queue, batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 226, in read_up_to
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 380, in _reader_read_up_to_v2
    num_records=num_records, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Error executing an HTTP request (HTTP response code 404, error code 0, error message '')
     when reading gs://project-166422-ml/User/flowers_User_20170522_121407/preproc/eval
     [[Node: ReaderReadUpToV2 = ReaderReadUpToV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordReaderV2, input_producer, ReaderReadUpToV2/num_records)]]
To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs: console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=123456234&resource=ml_job%2Fjob_id%2Fflowers_User_20170524_145125&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22ml_job%22%0Aresource.labels.job_id%3D%22flowers_User_20170524_145125%22"***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates a 404 not found when trying to read

```
gs://project-166422-ml/User/flowers_User_20170522_121407/preproc/eval
```

Does that file exist?

Based on the name I'm guessing that's evaluation data. So my guess is you are only running evaluation every 1000 steps which is why 1000 steps complete successfully. Then it tries to run evaluation and it fails because the data doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I looked through my folder structure and I attached a '/' after this user argument: --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval"  and that caused the erorr. Resolved now. For anyone that encounters such error DON'T do this: '--output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval/' like  I did which broke things.